# Is flu of our nose pure or impure and does it has any effect on Salah

Tags: salat, fiqh, taharah, najis

Is our Salah(Namaz) acceptable if previously flu from nose had fallen on our clothes and it had dried but we came to know about that after we were finished with Salah?
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

Nasal Mucus (مخاط) is considered ritually clean, it will not invalidate Salah if it is present on your body or clothing. From  [Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah 36/258](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk36/page/n258/mode/2up):

> [image]
>
> Mucus is defined as that which flows from the nose just like saliva flows from the mouth ...
>
> The jurists agree that mucus is ritually clean, and Salah is correct if it is offered in a cloth which is soiled with mucus.
>
> This is derived from the hadith:
>
> > "If one of you must spit, then let him spit to his left, beneath his foot. If he cannot do that, then let him do like this," and Al-Qasim described how he spat into his garment then rubbed part of it against another part."
> >
> > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:550a)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your prayer is accepted. Why would you think it won't be accepted? anything that comes out of your nose won't invalidate prayer even blood but the blood has to be small amount.